# Why does my method not work when I input a variable vs. inputting a string directly?

Tags: java, recursion

```
//method I'm trying to call
static String sentenceReversal(String input) {
        
            int x = input.indexOf(" ");
            
            //Base Case
            if(x == -1)
              return input;
              
             //Recursive Method
            return sentenceReversal(input.substring(x+1)) +" "+ input.substring(0, x);
```

```
case 6:
            System.out.println("Enter a string to reverse:");
            String input6 = scan.next();
            System.out.println(sentenceReversal(input6));
            break;
```

Calling the method as `sentenceReversal("Hello World")`

returns `World Hello`, but calling it with `input6` returns `Hello` and nothing else, any ideas?

I made a specific scanner only for this case as well because I was previously getting a `InputMismatchException`

Also when after inputting a number after the switch the next part of the string appears.

Comment: What if instead of using `scan`, you just assign `"Hello World"` to `input6`?

Comment: because `next()` reads only one word¹.... try printing the input just to check (is often helpful anyway) || **¹** `next()` actually returns the next token and, by default, whitespaces are used as delimiter || you can use `nextLine()` if you want to read the whole line (or change the delimiter)

Comment: Why is your method recursive. Isn't it easier to traverse back the string? Where did you get `InputMismatchException`? Post a stacktrace.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
 at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
 at CSDS233/csds233.Palindrome.main(Palindrome.java:137) //I made a new scanner because this scanner was also being used to control the switch statement I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**
Use `nextLine()` method instead of `next()` method.

**Reason:**
`next()` method is used to input String containing only 1 word whereas `nextLine()` method is used to input String containing multiple words. This is the reason your code is returning 'Hello' instead of 'World Hello' because it is taking only 'Hello' as the input and ignoring ' World'

**Your updated code:**

```
case 6:
        System.out.println("Enter a string to reverse:");
        String input6 = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println(sentenceReversal(input6));
        break;
```

Refer more methods of Scanner class at the below page:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java/util/Scanner.html#method_summary